# How to get the value from the other table if one table column is empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in my database

1. product
2. product_variations

**Both have price columns**.

If any product has variation then the **price** column of the **product table** will be nullified and the **price** column in the **variation table** will have some value.

But if product has no variation then the **price** column of product table will have some value but the **price** column in the **variation** table will not have a value

I want to fetch all the products having low to high price and vice versa.

```
$shopProducts = product::where(
    [
        "publish" => 'PUBLISH',
        'shop_id' => input::get('shopId')
    ]
)->orderBy('price', 'asc')
->paginate(12);
```

The above query is returning all the products in correct and place all those products at the end those have variation and have price column null.

But I want a query which checks first the price column of product and if it is null, then go to product variation table and search for a value and then return the result in either desc or asc.

Comment: Do you need, for eg. if a product has null price so get all variation of this product and join to the result?

Comment: yes i need a such solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a completely native way to do this with query builder, but if you're using a sql database you should be able to do this with a raw case statement.  For example ...

```
$shopProducts = product::SELECT(
    DB::raw("CASE WHEN product_variations.price IS NULL THEN product.price ELSE product_variations.price END AS price")
)->where(
    [
        "publish" => 'PUBLISH',
        'shop_id' => input::get('shopId')
    ]
)->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN product_variations.price IS NULL THEN product.price ELSE product_variations.price END', 'asc')
->paginate(12);
```

That should work with mssql or mysql and most databases support some type of similar syntax. You'll just need to add any additional columns you want to your select statement.  You will also need to join your product_variations table for this method to work.

The raw select and raw order by both bypass Laravel's query builder and pass your statements directly to the database, so just be careful how you construct your queries.  Laravel won't sanitize those for you.